# how best to locate openssh credentials for powershell script run by SYSTEM

Tags: ssh, powershell, openssh

I've got a powershell script in the form

```
$commands = @"
    echo "1 + 2" | bc
"@

$commands | ssh user@1.2.3.4
```

Right now what I'm doing is setting up ssh keys once ahead of time, but the problem is that the caller of my script is a service run in the SYSTEM user space, which, in turn, means that none of my ssh keys generated for `administrator` or `user1234` are getting used. *annoyingly, this actually causes the powershell ssh client to hang.*

Whats the best solution and does anybody have some code to get me started?

1. I could do some powershell `runas` foo to swap around between users, to give me a kind of user "hard-point" for ssh
2. I could move the ssh keys from their default home of `~/.ssh`, though I really dont know what is safe and what isn't here
3. I could, at an obnoxious operational cost, stop using a service with the SYSTEM user and try to run said service as a user every time I come into the office.

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no PowerShell SSH client. I guess you're using WSL and the regular WSL ssh? Depending on how you're running that script you could also just give it a user and wouldn't need manually run it every time you come into the office. [Going by this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account) it would appear that the default user home should be its home.

Comment: Suggestion: Use [psexec -s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to generate or import your keys into the System account.

Comment: @Seth Powershell does have SSh support in v 6.  https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Comment: Have you looked to use the PowerShell SSH module from the MS PowerShellGallery --- Find-Module -Name '*ssh*'

Comment: @uSlackr thanks, that's interesting to know. Still, if you look at what the OP does, it's clear he's not using a cmdlet but rather just pipes the input to the/a OpenSSH port. The module for ssh doesn't contain any functions to actually use SSH in a PowerShell way but rather just a port of SSH for Windows and an OpenSSHUtils module. Though it's good to know it's not utilizing WSL. Posh-SSH would be an actual PowerShell module that lets you utilize SSH in a PowerShell way.

Comment: Looks as though he may be using the Win32 project and opened an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1287

Comment: @uSlackr thats correct, I'm sorry Im not really steeped in ssh vernacular, and I was fairly certain that I'd gotten my ssh client through chocolaty. I did make that issue, since, IMHO, not failing with some kind of error is a bug. But now that you guys have pointed out the many different options for ssh I'm not sure what I should do. Should I just remove my open ssh installation, grab posh-git, and call it a day?